# Is there a term for a product having the same name as its place of origin?

Tags: phrases, terminology

Several trade products, especially food, have been named after their places of origin throughout the centuries. To mention just a few,

- *champagne*, after Champagne, France.
- *calico*, after Calicut, India
- *cashmere*, after Kashmir, India/Pakistan
- *port*, after Oporto, Portugal
- *muslin*, after Mosul, Iraq
- *alsatian* (a German shephard) after Alsace, France
- *china* (tableware), after China
- *canary*, Canary Islands
- *spa*, after Spa, Belgium

Is there, in linguistics, a phrase or term for naming something after its place of origin?

Edit - Re Tim's answer, although most of them are trade products, the term I'm looking for also includes animals, behaviors, recipes, etc.

Comment: Ah, and let's not forget "frankfurter" and "hamburger"!

Comment: The word for something named after a **person** in particular is 'eponymous'. However, I am aware this isn't as broad a definition as you are asking for.

Comment: So, do you want to include things named after a place even if that's _not_ the origin of whatever that thing is?

Comment: @mattdm  humm, I'd better remove "lesbian".

Comment: Ok, guys, I've removed "lesbian".  You're right, I shouldn't have included it.

Comment: I think "lesbian" could be included with a different phrasing of the question (not restricting to food/products)

Comment: @ypercube  I would have to rephrase the question and, unable to do it at that moment, I decided to remove "lesbian, after Lesbos, Greece".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the word you are looking for is toponym. I also think that a list of 'trade products' that includes *lesbian* needs work (unless your supermarkets are markedly different from ours).

Comment: Tim, please see edit.

Comment: @Resquiens: I couldn't resist looking into that one! Having discovered from Wikipedia that olive oil is the main source of income for the island, I searched Google Books for [*lesbian olive oil*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22flakey%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&q=%22lesbian+olive+oil%22). The only written instance I found there obviously meant *for female homosexuals*, rather than *from Lesbos*. OED tells me there's such a thing as *a lesbian rule* (bendy, made of lead so it can measure round corners), but I never heard of that before.

Comment: Although it _seems_ like this might be the right word, I don't think it is. Toponym just means _any place name_.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: So lesbians use _special_ olive oil? This is going to keep me awake tonight..... This is reminding me of playground jokes of 55 years ago: how do you make a Venetian blind? Poke him in the eye. How do you make a Swiss roll? Push him down the mountainside.

Comment: @mattdm: I also have my doubts. I suspect there simply *isn't* a word meaning ***location** name which in extended use identifies a **product** associated with that location*. The same occurs with adjectival forms derived from the place name - thus ***scotch*** identifies *whisky [originally and usually, **from Scotland**, but not necessarily]*, leading to the somewhat curious [*Do you drink Irish scotch, Detective?*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22drink+irish+scotch%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: *Toponym* is correct, thanks to its extended meaning. It refers to either a place name or a word derived from a place name. Another interesting term is *epotoponym* which is a place name  that constitutes the basis or origin of a common noun. For example, the region Champagne is an *epotoponym*.

Answer (score 5):

While this is the "English Language & Usage" part of stackexchange your answer mentions "in linguistics". There is also an internationally recognized legal term that protects these names to indicate authenticity, the French "Appellation d'origine contrôlée". Roquefort cheese, Cognac, Porto, Lambic beers, and others benefit from this protection. In many countries the abbreviation "AOC" is more widely used as and there are direct and loose translations in the English, Spanish and Italian languages. Wikipedia has more about this [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appellation_d%27origine_contr%C3%B4l%C3%A9e).

Answer (score 0):

**Geographical Indication**: is a sign used on products that have a specific geographical origin and possess qualities or a reputation that are due to that origin.

The sign must identify the product as originating in a given place.

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_indication
http://www.wipo.int/geo_indications/en/
```